# Backtesting GARCH model in R

Tags: r, garch, finance, volatility-forecasting

I used garch to predict the volatility of shopify(SHOP.TO) . I used `ugarchroll` to backtest my GARCH model but my mean absolute percentage error was incredibly high: it is around 1.2 . I would like to know why my mean absolute percentage error was so high and if I can improve my model by changing any parameters.

```
library(rugarch)
getSymbols("SHOP.TO")

rets = na.omit(ROC(SHOP.TO$SHOP.TO.Close))

tgarch = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                    variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"),
                    distribution.model = "sstd")
garchroll<-ugarchroll(tgarch, data = rets,n.start =500, 
                      refit.window="moving", refit.every =200)


coef(garchroll)[(1)]
coef(garchroll)[(3)]
preds<-as.data.frame(garchroll)

#prediction error
e=(preds$Realized-preds$Mu)/preds$Realized
mean(abs(e))
``
```

Comment: In `preds$Realized-preds$Mu/preds$Realized`, don't you need to put the difference in parentheses before dividing?

Comment: thank you I just made the edit but why is my mean absolute percentage error so high . Is there any way I can change the paremeters to my model to make it better

Comment: In your original question, you were worried it was too low; now it is too high. Which one is it after the code correction? In any case, it seems you are looking at point forecasts and using an ARMA(1,1) model for that. Changing that to ARMA(0,0) might make sense if you are dealing with asset returns or the like that are essentially unpredictable. I doubt that would improve the forecasts all that much, though; unpredictable means unpredictable. If you are interested in forecasting volatility, you should assess forecasts of volatility rather than point forecasts.